# Custom ListView item click event is not working

Tags: android, textview, listviewitem, onitemclicklistener

My app is supporting ADA compliance. For that I have added

```
 android:focusable="true"
```

property for custom `ListView` items (3-4 TextViews). But after this my `ListView` item click event is not working. When I removed above property from list items, it is working fine. But for ADA compliance I need this. How can I resolve this issue?

EDIT:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:nextFocusForward="@+id/city"
        android:text="****"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/city"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:nextFocusForward="@+id/address"
        android:text="5145 N"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TX 78731"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: list row having edit text? Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602924/android-listview-item-click-is-not-working/23603110#23603110

Comment: try by changing it to false

Comment: can you please post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the textview of your inflator layout just add:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

and in parent layout of your inflator i.e in relative layout of inflator add:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove above line from your code and give `android:clickable="false"` and `android:focusable="false"` to your all the textview, so your textviews will not have focus and clicks, so your item click will work.

Comment: but if i remove android:focusable="true" my app will not support ADA.

Comment: I have added that flag to make my app ADA compliant. If there is any other way to make it ADA compliant I am ready to remove this.else not.

Comment: ADA compliant, I didnt get it, can you please explain me.?

Comment: ADA stands for American Disability Act.. That means blind people should be able to use our app. In IOS there is functionality called voice over. Like that I have to make my application useful for blind people also. For that every component in the app should be focusable and contain a content description.

Comment: @seethalakshmi ok thanks for explanation. So in short, yo need all the component should be focusable, right?

Comment: if ADA complaince is possible without setting focusable flag then i am ready to remove this flag.

Comment: @seethalakshmi in this case you must need to use these attributes, but with some other pattern, like below answer of Dev's, you can try it.